MariaDB databases and users created via PHP script not visible in Plesk
I've encountered an issue where MariaDB databases and users created via PHP scripts are not visible in the Plesk control panel. While the databases and users are fully functional and accessible through direct SQL queries or other database management tools, they do not appear in the Plesk interface, which prevents me from managing them through Plesk. When I open PhpMyAdmin via "Database Servers" is see the added database, but the count in Plesk is wrong. I want to be able to manage MariaDB users and databases via Plesk when I added them via a PHP script.
Any help would be appreciated.

The server management platform built with you in mind.  Because it's a server management tool, the functionality of Plesk is wider than just MySQL users.  (But the question is still: offtopic)
